# Visual Studio: ToolsVersion vs PlatformToolset. Do they need to correspond?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

The MSDN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170) says that you need to use the Runtime version that correpsonds to the Platform Toolset version, hence it leads to UB otherwise.
I have a legacy project that was migrated to Visual Studio 2019, and has a `<PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>` but `<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`.
I know that there should be `ToolsVersion="Current"` or `ToolsVersion="16.0"` which is generated by CMake.
I get no warnings from Visual Studio when building the project, but I am concerned if specifing incompatible versions will lead to linking the wrong CRT version.

When I build with `/MD` it seems that everything is ok:

```
  Image has the following dependencies:

    msi.dll
    MSVCP140D.dll
    VCRUNTIME140D.dll
    VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll
    ucrtbased.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
```

But the legacy project uses `/MT` and I can't determine which CRT is used from the `dumpbin` output for `.obj` file:

```
   Linker Directives
   -----------------
   /FAILIFMISMATCH:_MSC_VER=1900
   /FAILIFMISMATCH:_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2
   /FAILIFMISMATCH:RuntimeLibrary=MTd_StaticDebug
   /DEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd
   /FAILIFMISMATCH:_CRT_STDIO_ISO_WIDE_SPECIFIERS=0
   /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
   /DEFAULTLIB:LIBCMTD
   /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
```

*Is ToolsVersion even meaningfull and can it lead to linking the wrong CRT version?*
*How can I inspect which version of Runtime is linked when compiled with `/MT`?*

---

From the page about [binary compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170):

> You can mix binaries built by different versions of the v140, v141, v142, and v143 toolsets. However, you must link by using a toolset at least as recent as the most recent binary in your app. Here's an example: you can link an app compiled using any 2017 toolset (v141, versions 15.0 through 15.9) to a static library compiled using, say, Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2 (v142). You just have to link them by using a version 16.2 or later toolset. You can link a version 16.2 library to a version 16.4 app as long as you use a 16.4 or later toolset.

So my concern is about some libraries to be built with `ToolsVersion="4.0"`, which will not be compatible with binaries build by versions `v140`..`v142`.
Hence the question: **will anything bad happen if instead of version 15.0 with v141 PlatformToolset a 4.0 ToolsVersion is be used?**

Answer (score 1):

`ToolsVersion` is an [optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/project-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022#attributes-and-elements) attribute and used only by msbuild.
It is the version of the Toolset MSBuild uses to [determine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion?view=vs-2022) the values for `$(MSBuildBinPath)` and `$(MSBuildToolsPath)`.
You can safely omit this attribute, it won't affect your ABI.

Comment: By omitting you mean to remove it from xml or leave it as it is `4.0`?

Comment: Remove it completely

Comment: ok, but the question is "does it affect the ABI when it is *present and does not correspond*". Also, how can I see how MSBuild resolved `$(MSBuildToolsPath)` and `$(MSBuildToolsPath)` after the solution has been built via the command line `msbuild.exe`?